# visual c++ include and link libraries

Tags: visual-c++, include

I have a old install of visual c++ 6.0.  I'd like to bring things more nearly up to date particularly for include files.  Here is a list of what my TOOLS->OPTIONS->DIRECTORIES->INCLUDE FILES shows...

c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include

c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\mfc\include

c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\atl\include

c:\windows\microsoftnet\framework\v2.0.50727

c:\program files\microsoft html help workshop\include

c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0\include

So, the questions is: Are there newer versions of these include directories compatible with my visual c++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last SDK that works with VC 6.0 is the February 2003 Edition. .Net 2.0 SDK and 
Windows 7 SDK won't work with VC6. Since you put them after VC6's include path, they are likely not used anyway.

Html help workshop has not been updated since 2003. It works with VC6.

Comment: @sheng Jiang:  So you are suggesting I remove the microsoftnet\v2.0.5027 and sdks\windows\v7.0 include, RIGHT?  Would the sdk from February 2003 have things not in the two vc98 include paths?  I don't know where the net include came from but I'm sure I added the sdk 7 one in an attempt to get something going.

Comment: Yes, new APIs such as IE5 or Windows 2000 APIs are not in VC6. I would suggest you upgrade your Visual C++, if you plan to use Windows 7 APIs.